# Installing PMD 5.3.3 on Eclipse Neon

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pmd

I'm trying to install the latest version of PMD on a fresh installation of Eclipse Neon.

I've tried installing it by adding the site http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/pmd-eclipse/update-site/

but it gives me the following error:

```
Unable to read repository at http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/pmd-eclipse/update-site/content.xml.
Unable to read repository at http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/pmd-eclipse/update-site/content.xml.
Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

I've tried disabling my firewall and anti-virus, changing my Network Connection Active Provider to Native and Direct, but it still does not work.

I've tried downloading the zip file (pmd-bin-5.3.3.zip) from the PMD site and tried adding it through "Install new Software" > "Add" > "Archive" but that did not work.

I've tried making a subfolder in my eclipse/dropins directory and extracting the PMD zip file there but that also does not work.

I can access the internet via Eclipse if I open up the Internet Browser view. I've also installed EclEmma and FindBugs via the Marketplace as well as CheckStyle via Install New Software > Add > Archive.

I've also tried reloading the software site via Preferences > Install/Update > Available Software Sites.

I've been looking for solutions online but none so far have worked. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some known problems that can occur while installing pmd-eclipse from the update site hosted at sourceforge, see https://github.com/pmd/pmd-eclipse-plugin/issues/19

To workaround all these problems, follow these instructions:

- Download the update site for the latest pmd-eclipse-plugin version as a zip-file from there: https://github.com/pmd/pmd-eclipse-plugin/releases
- In eclipse, go to: Help > Install new Software > Add > Archive and select the update-site zip file (e.g. "net.sourceforge.pmd.eclipse.p2updatesite-4.0.11.v20170128-2103.zip")

Please note: you have been trying to install PMD (pmd-bin-5.3.3.zip) directly into eclipse - this won't work. You'll need to install the [pmd-eclipse-plugin](https://github.com/pmd/pmd-eclipse-plugin) - this already includes PMD.

Btw. there is also an alternative pmd eclipse plugin available: https://acanda.github.io/eclipse-pmd/